# Finding a specific point on a logarithmic scale

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions

I've been racking my head around this issue for a while now, watching videos and searching on Google, but to no avail.

What I am trying to do is to find an equation that enables me to note with a pencil on a drawn-to-scale logarithmic scale, where a certain number is. For example, in the picture below, I'd like to find out which point on the scale will I be able to note the number $20$.

Hand-drawn log scale -
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tick values are given by

$$3^i$$ where $i$ is the tick index, starting at $i=1$ on the left.

Now the equation

$$3^x=20$$

has the solution

$$x=\log_320\approx2.73$$ so that the number $20$ lies at $73\%$ of the second interval (about third quarter).

[image]

---

As you can check, $$3^{2\frac34}=9\sqrt{\sqrt{3^3}}\approx20.5$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

How do you know that the number $3$ is one unit to the right of the origin? Answer: $\log_33$

How do you know that the number $9$ is two units to the right of the origin? Answer: $\log_39$

So, how do you know where the number $20$ is on the scale?

Comment: Using the log base 3 of 20, I'll get 2.73. This would mean its 2 units to the right of the origin, and 73% of the way to the third unit. Is that correct?

Comment: @JohnFaustian That is absolutely correct. Well done!